# c++ how to delete thread once it has been terminated

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm working on a project that uses uses a thread to connect to a server. Whenever the login button is pressed, it initialized a thread to log in with the given IP and port provided by the user.

**ServerPage.h**

```cpp
class ServerPage {
public:
    static std::thread serverThread;
    
    static void login();
}
```

**ServerPage.cpp**

```cpp
#include "ServerPage.h"

std::thread ServerPage::serverThread;

void ServerPage::login() {
    while (/*server is not connected*/) {
        if (/*button is clicked and thread is not running*/)
        serverThread = std::thread(Client::init, ip, port);
    }
}
```

This works well until the button is clicked more than once. I'm able to use the `Client` class to see the status of the server (connected, not connected, or failure) Is there a way to delete or re initialize so that it can be run until the client is connected?

Comment: I usually use a flag (`std::atomic<bool>`) to indicate if a thread is currently running.

Comment: Why are you using a `static` variable if there can be multiple threads created?

Comment: Do you mean you want to stop a running thread before creating a new one? Or do you want to stop a new thread from starting if the old one is still running?

Comment: @mdf I'm able to tell if the thread is still running. I'm just having trouble restarting it

Comment: @rustyx I don't want to stop the thread. The thread return whenever it has an error or is successful. I'm able to figure out whether it was successful or not. I just need no know how to restart the thread with new `port` and `ip` variables

Comment: @RemyLebeau I don't want multiple threads. I want a single thread that can be restarted.

Comment: @ArnoldPalmer threads can't be restarted. You have to create a new thread each time. If you want only 1 thread running at a time, it would be better to create 1 thread that loops, performing a login per iteration, sleeping in between iterations as needed. For instance, use a `condition_variable` or other signal that the thread can wait on inside the loop, and then have your main code wake up the thread with a signal whenever a new login is needed.

Comment: Terminology: you can't `delete` it if you didn't `new` it. But neither of those is appropriate here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all: threads cannot be restarted. There is no such concept in programming. Unless by "restart" you mean "kill and spawn again".

It is not possible to kill a thread in a cross-platform way. For posix (I don't know about other OS) you can use pthreads (instead of std::thread) and send kill signal to it and spawn it again. But this is a ninja way, not necessarily what you should do. For example if you kill a thread that currently holds a lock, you will end up in a deadlock. This method should be avoided. However, if you can't modify `Client::init` method, then there might be no other choice without weakening your requirements.

A better solution is to pass around "cancellation tokens": small objects that you can register cancel handlers on it. Then you implement `Client::init` to cancel itself (and do any necessary cleanup, like releasing locks) whenever cancellation is triggered. Which you trigger on click.